# How to support Japanese on English RedHat 4.8?

Tags: redhat, language

I have a few users who have requested the ability to read/write Japanese on their RedHat 4.8 English workstations.  I installed the standard English 4.8 distribution and was curious if there was a application/package/etc... that could be installed to give multi-language support?  On their windows machines they use IME, but I not sure if something similar exists for Linux.  Other versions of RedHat/Linux are not an option, since they have existing applications installed that can only be run with RH v4.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to [install the appropriate language packages](http://docs.redhat.com/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/5/html/International_Language_Support_Guide/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_International_Language_Support_Guide-Installing_and_supporting_languages.html).  Then the users just set the appropriate LANG/LOCALE environment variables (or desktop manager preferences) and stuff Just Works :-)

Comment: I can't believe I missed that page, I must have googled all the wrong terms... Very clear and exactly what I need... Thanks!

Comment: The magical search term I used was `redhat language package` (looking for the generic instructions) - of course my Google algorithm is perturbed by all the *nix stuff I search for which helps things like this float to the top :)

Comment: This doesn't show for version 4.8, it shows it only works for 5.0?  Do you know if this will also work for 4.8 ?

Comment: it should be pretty similar - just poke around in your settings panels for language preferences (or search your yum/RPM repository for "japanese" or "jp" language stuff and you should find packages that fit the bill)

Comment: KDE-I1AN-Japanese-3.3.1-2.1 was the only package I could find in RPM and I installed/checked languages and it didn't show up... Any other suggestions?